# RadioGroup in a Gridview

Tags: android, listview

i want make Grid view in radio group

i made current grid view but the radiobuttons is not in radiogroub

i searched in google but i dont found anything

this is my classes and xml files please help me in this

AddCtegory_Activity.java

```
public class AddCategory_Activity extends Activity {

ExpandableHeightGridView grid;
int[] web = {
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,11,12,13,14,15,16
} ;
int[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.c_1,
        R.drawable.c_2,
        R.drawable.c_3,
        R.drawable.c_4,
        R.drawable.c_5,
        R.drawable.c_6,
        R.drawable.c_7,
        R.drawable.c_8,
        R.drawable.c_9,
        R.drawable.c_10,
        R.drawable.c_11,
        R.drawable.c_12,
        R.drawable.c_13,
        R.drawable.c_14,
        R.drawable.c_15,
        R.drawable.c_16
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /************************* Start Action Bar Function ************************************/
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffffff")));
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back_icon);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP|ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    /************************* End Action Bar Function ************************************/
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_category_);
    /*******************************************************/
    CustomGridAdapterAddCategoryListColor adapters = new CustomGridAdapterAddCategoryListColor(AddCategory_Activity.this, web, imageId);
    grid=(ExpandableHeightGridView)findViewById(R.id.color_grid);
    grid.setExpanded(true);
    grid.setAdapter(adapters);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(AddCategory_Activity.this, "You Clicked at " + web[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

     /********************************************************/

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_category_, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and this is adapter

```
public class CustomGridAdapterAddCategoryListColor extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private final int[] title;
    private final int[] Imageid;

    public CustomGridAdapterAddCategoryListColor(Context c, int[] title, int[] Imageid) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return title.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_new_category_grid_list_item, null);

            RadioButton rp = (RadioButton) grid.findViewById(R.id.rbColor);
            rp.setBackgroundResource(Imageid[position]);
            rp.setId(title[position]);

        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        return grid;
    }

}
```

this is Grid item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="40pt"
    android:layout_height="40pt"
    android:id="@+id/rbColor"
    android:button="@null"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/button"/>
```

and in finaly XML layout

```
<RadioGroup

        android:id="@+id/radioGroub_listColor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <info.androidhive.slidingmenu.model.ExpandableHeightGridView
            android:id="@+id/color_grid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:numColumns="4"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bordertop_gridview"
            />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Why do you use third party libraries for sliding menu when google added support for it, which name is DrawerLayout, which is more easier to customize that library that you used.

Comment: no i want make sliding menu like facebook application